# Laserlight - Fog Density?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

Trying to make something like those laser lights.

For the laser itself i found a lot of stuff on youtube, but when it comes to the details im not sure. Its just consistent in those tutorials when it comes to the beam. But i want some variations like it is in the pictures. The fourth picture is a really good ref, so you can see the smoke/variation in the light a lot. Would be interested to do this in Eevee & cycles just to learn from it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simple one for your last reference image ... procedural texture for triangle object ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks perfect! I will give it a try! Thanks @vklidu !

Comment: This shader is not producing the first front rays, what I did is more like a faked solution. To create something more realistic for different kind of laser show you would need to work with Volumetric shader, Motion Blur, and other stuff ... but that is quite complex to achieve and I even know if you need animation or a still image.